# Redirect anything not already redirected with 301 on IIS7

Tags: iis, redirect, web-config, seo, http-status-code-301

We recently setup a new website on a new domain using WordPress, to replace our old website using flat files. Because of time constraints, we had little time to plan and ended up having someone setup the redirects in IIS Manager.

This means that almost every folder in the old website has something like the following for each page:

```
<location path="old-file.html">
    <system.webServer>
        <httpRedirect enabled="true" destination="http://new-domain.com/new-page/" exactDestination="true" childOnly="true" httpResponseStatus="Permanent" />
    </system.webServer>
</location>
```

The problem is that this was a massive site with ~15k pages and only about 1k pages were manually redirected to new URIs. This means we have potentially 14k pages of legacy content (effectively dead URLs, some of it is so old) but we need to it redirect to the root of the new domain.

So almost every folder has a web.config with one instance of the codeblock above for each page redirected, but we need every page that wasn't redirected in this manner to redirect to a fixed location.

Manually configuring isn't an option because of the number of pages. I thought about using a tool to add a line of PHP to handle the redirect to every .php and .html file (PHP had to parse html files on this site for legacy content) but it's far from ideal.

Ideally, there'd be something I could put in the web.config which would say "For any request not already redirected via `<location>`, redirect it to "http:// domain.com". Even if this meant appending something to the web.config already in each folder, it would save days of work, say if no locations match, then redirect.

I've searched for having multiple locations or wildcards in `<location>` blocks but doesn't seem possible so I'm not sure what do do here—any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion: why not you redirect your 404 page to home page of any other you wish to.. if someone lands to any old page that no longer exists should go to 404 so redirect 404 to homepage, common practice in case of ecommerce sites they redirect their discontinued product page to search page. If that helps you can google "redirect 404 to homepage wordpress" there are lots of plugins that would do it, but as IIS you can simply config your web.config.

Answer (score 0):

If the urls are now dead and you dont have replacement content to redirect them to, then the proper response would be to return a 404/410. Redirecting dead urls in bulk to the homepage will be seen by Google as a soft 404. https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/181708?hl=en

Comment: Usually I'd agree, but unfortunately they have to be redirected. How would you go about returning a 404 in this case though?